# I want to output MAX (value) over following 30 minutes IF current row value is > 10 and previous row is <10

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using data mytable

`date   value
2019-07-11 02:20:00 UTC 14.99
2019-07-11 02:30:00 UTC 12.53
2019-07-11 02:40:00 UTC 12.53
2019-07-11 02:50:00 UTC 14.99
2019-07-11 03:00:00 UTC 10.07
2019-07-11 03:10:00 UTC 7.61
2019-07-11 03:20:00 UTC 7.61
2019-07-11 03:30:00 UTC 10.07
2019-07-11 03:40:00 UTC 10.07
2019-07-11 03:50:00 UTC 7.61
2019-07-11 04:00:00 UTC 7.61
2019-07-11 04:10:00 UTC 7.61`:

I want to output MAX (value) over following 30 minutes IF current row value is > 10 and previous row is < 10.

For example, if value is >10, check previous row value is <10. If this is true, output MAX(value) over 30 minutes following current row. For the table above, the first value that this would output should be 10.07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  CASE value > 10 AND prev_value < 10
    WHEN TRUE THEN 
      MAX(value) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(ts) RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1800 FOLLOWING)
    ELSE NULL
  END max_value_next_30_min
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(value) OVER(ORDER BY ts) prev_value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- ORDER BY ts
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-07-11 02:20:00 UTC' ts, 14.99 value UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 02:30:00 UTC', 12.53 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 02:40:00 UTC', 12.53 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 02:50:00 UTC', 14.99 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 03:00:00 UTC', 10.07 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 03:10:00 UTC', 7.61 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 03:20:00 UTC', 7.61 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 03:30:00 UTC', 10.07 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 03:40:00 UTC', 10.07 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 03:50:00 UTC', 17.61 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11 04:00:00 UTC', 7.61 UNION ALL 
  SELECT '2019-07-11 04:10:00 UTC', 7.61
)
SELECT *, 
  CASE value > 10 AND prev_value < 10
    WHEN TRUE THEN 
      MAX(value) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(ts) RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1800 FOLLOWING)
    ELSE NULL
  END max_value_next_30_min
FROM (
  SELECT *, LAG(value) OVER(ORDER BY ts) prev_value
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
-- ORDER BY ts
```

with output

```
Row ts                      value   prev_value  max_value_next_30_min    
1   2019-07-11 02:20:00 UTC 14.99   null        null     
2   2019-07-11 02:30:00 UTC 12.53   14.99       null     
3   2019-07-11 02:40:00 UTC 12.53   12.53       null     
4   2019-07-11 02:50:00 UTC 14.99   12.53       null     
5   2019-07-11 03:00:00 UTC 10.07   14.99       null     
6   2019-07-11 03:10:00 UTC 7.61    10.07       null     
7   2019-07-11 03:20:00 UTC 7.61    7.61        null     
8   2019-07-11 03:30:00 UTC 10.07   7.61        17.61    
9   2019-07-11 03:40:00 UTC 10.07   10.07       null     
10  2019-07-11 03:50:00 UTC 17.61   10.07       null     
11  2019-07-11 04:00:00 UTC 7.61    17.61       null     
12  2019-07-11 04:10:00 UTC 7.61    7.61        null
```

Comment: Ah yes! This is perfect. I was over complicating this with creating additional tables to join on that are the 30 minute increment. Thanks a ton for your help.